# Java Regular Expression - Characters "(" and ")"Matches the Pattern "[\\p{Alpha} '-,.]"

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, match

I have been wondering why characters `"("` and `")"` matches the pattern `"[\\p{Alpha} '-,.]"`.

Please take a look at my code. The method `matches` will return `true` for the characters `"("` and `")"`.

Also, are there any other characters that will return `true` if I tried to match is with my pattern?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "[\\p{Alpha} '-,.]";
        //String text = "(";
        String text = ")";
        System.out.print(Pattern.matches(pattern, text));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `'-,` is interpeted as range and is equivalent to `'()*+,`, try to escape minus character `"[\\p{Alpha} '\\-,.]"`

Comment: I see. I have escaped the - symbol in my pattern. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just double escape the `)` symbol,

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "[\\p{Alpha} '-,.]";
        //String text = "(";
        String text = "\\)";
        System.out.print(Pattern.matches(pattern, text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Avinash. This actually worked. But I would like to know why. By the way, thank you! + for this solution.

Comment: This is wrong.  The `matches()` method requires the regex to match the whole of the target string, so in this case it acts as if the regex were `\A[\p{Alpha} '-,.]\z`.  There's no `+` or `*` after the closing `]`, so this regex can only match a string that's one character long.  You added another character **to the target string**, so of course it doesn't match any more.  If you were to use `find()` instead of `matches()`, you would find it skips the `\` but still incorrectly matches the `)`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks for your info. Does it works if he won't place `\\` before `)` ?

Comment: D'oh! I didn't notice the messed-up formatting in my comment.  And yours is messed up too, so I'll just wing it.  The problem is in the regex, so it makes no sense trying to fix the target string.  Either escape the hyphen with a backslash as the accepted answer says (`[\p{Alpha} '\-,.]`), or move it to the end where the regex compiler knows it should match a literal hyphen (`[\p{Alpha} ',.-]`).